# Ubuntu, Dual Monitor - Issue on boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot, laptop, multiple-monitors

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 on a laptop on a dock with an outboard (desktop) display.  When plugged in to the dock, I am only using the desktop display, not the laptop's.  When I boot, the laptop display shows a screen to unlock my (LUKS) disks.  Twelve second later, the desktop screen shows that password prompt.

1. Is there some way to eliminate that interminable wait??
2. I am not using the nvidia drivers yet.  Do I have to do something different if I do?  I ask because I've seen in the past that the drivers lead to a different kind of password prompt: a colored background with a text password request line.

I have already copied `~/.config/monitors.xml` to `~gdm/.config/`.  That moved the subsequent login prompt to my desktop display and works fine.  Next question is:

3. I would like for all this to work when I start the laptop while the lid is closed.  What do I have to do for that to work?